# How to prevent submit button submitting a form using Foundation 6.6 and Abide

Tags: forms, zurb-foundation, abide

I am trying to use Foundation 6.6 Abide to validate a form and if the form is valid, I DO NOT want it to submit - but rather trigger another another event. Whatever I do - the form always seem to submit.

```
<form data-abide novalidate id="contactForm" >
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Next " id="goToBillingAddressTab"/>
</form>
```

I have added this code - but it always submits.

```
// script to prevent form from submitting 
$('#contactForm').on("submit", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submit for form intercepted");
      return false;
  });

// script to trigger other events 
    $('#contactForm').on("formvalid.zf.abide", function(ev,frm) {
      console.log("Form is valid");
      ev.preventDefault(); // also added prevent submit here
      // perform other tasks here

      return false; // and another version of prevent submit
  });
```

I have also tried this - but it still submits:

```
  $('#contactForm').on("submit", function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log("Submit for form intercepted");
  return false;
});


$('#contactForm').on("formvalid.zf.abide", function(ev) {
console.log("Form is valid");
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
    ev.preventDefault();
    // perform other task

    return false;
});
```

Comment: The events are bound on the submit buttons as it seems and you may need stopPropagation and stopImmediatePropagation. https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/v6.6.1/js/foundation.abide.js#L71

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but it still submits..

Comment: Perhaps check validation on each input then enable your button to be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION!

I was using the "DOWNLOAD VERSION" of Foundation 6.6.1. That is where the bug creeps in somewhere.

If I use the CDNS:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.6.1/js/foundation.min.js

Then it works as it should